# Need help - php save .txt

Tags: php

I need your help. 
I need to every time the code stores the information in txt file, then each new record to the new line and what should be done to all be numbered?

```
<?php
$txt = "data.txt"; 
if (isset($_POST['Password'])) { // check if both fields are set
    $fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
    $txt=$_POST['Password']; 
    fwrite($fh,$txt); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
}
?>
```

Comment: it is just an example

Comment: Samuel, if he is asking for help saving a text file, the OP is either new to programming or new to PHP. How is this meant to help them?

Comment: @HarryTorry things you get used to are hard to erase. Personally if somebody has problems with an SQL query not working and is not aware that he is prone to sql injection I still point that out. I'll try to hint that just if code works doesn't mean it should be used. But you are right I should have made this optional point more clear. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: For the sake of explaining how to actually do this, you will need to encrypt the $txt variable.

 $txt = crypt( $_post['Password'], 'this text helps to make your passwords more secure, you can put anything you want in here');

Comment: Use `PHP_EOL` for new line. Usage: `$str = 'This is a string'. PHP_EOL ;`

Answer (score 1):

Added some comments to explain the changes.

```
<?php
$file = "data.txt";  // check if both fields are set
$fh = fopen($file, 'a+'); //open the file for reading, writing and put the pointer at the end of file.  

$word=md5(rand(1,10)); //random word generator for testing
fwrite($fh,$word."\n"); // Write information to the file add a new line to the end of the word.
 
rewind($fh); //return the pointer to the start of the text file.
$lines = explode("\n",trim(fread($fh, filesize($file)))); // create an array of lines.

foreach($lines as $key=>$line){ // iterate over each line.
    echo $key." : ".$line."<br>";
}
fclose($fh); // Close the file
?>
```

PHP

[fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

[fread](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)

[explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in a more simpler way..

```
<?php
$txt = "data.txt"; 
if (isset($_POST['Password']) && file_exists($txt))
    { 
      file_put_contents($txt,$_POST['Password'],FILE_APPEND);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

we open file to write into it ,you must make handle to `a+` like [ php doc ][1]
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

So your code will be :

```
<?php
$fileName = "data.txt";  // change variable name to file name
if (isset($_POST['Password'])) { // check if both fields are set
    $file = fopen($fileName, 'a+'); // set handler to a+   
    $txt=$_POST['Password']; 
    fwrite($file,$txt); // Write information to the file
    fclose($file); // Close the file
}
?>
```

Comment: `w` place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. You would only ever save the last password.